# Xamarin Forms SQlite ID AutoIncrement Not Working

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to insert some values into sqlite database. ID  has primarykey,autoincrement properties. First value has inserted successfully. When inserting for the second time, ID is not incrementing.So values are inserted again and again,not updating.I have installed sqlite-net-pcl library.Help Please..

```
using PCLStorage;
using SQLite;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;


public class SQLHelper
    {
        static object locker = new object();

        readonly SQLiteConnection database;

        public SQLHelper()
        {
            database = GetConnection();
            // create the tables  
            database.CreateTable<Offline>();
            database.CreateTable<Category>();
            database.CreateTable<Product>();
            database.CreateTable<Password>();
        }

        public SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
        {
            SQLiteConnection sqlitConnection;
            var sqliteFilename = "Offline.db";
            IFolder folder = PCLStorage.FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
            string path = PortablePath.Combine(folder.Path.ToString(), 
            sqliteFilename);
            sqlitConnection = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(path);
            return sqlitConnection;
        }     

public long Save_password(Password password)
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                if (password.p_id != 0)
                {
                    return database.Update(password);
                }
                else
                {
                    return database.Insert(password);
                }


            }
        }
}

public class Password 
    {                            
        [PrimaryKey,AutoIncrement]
        public long p_id { set; get; }              

        public string password { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string tb_num { get; set; }        
    }
```

cs page:

```
                    string lbl_1 = e1.Text;
                    string lbl_2 = e2.Text;
                    if (lbl_1.Equals(lbl_2))
                    {
                        Password password = new Password();
                        password.password = lbl_2;
                        long i = App.Database.Save_password(password);
                        if (i > 0)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine(i);
                            DependencyService.Get<IToast>().LongAlert("Success");
                        }

                        Navigation.PopAsync();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DependencyService.Get<IToast>().LongAlert("Passwords Mismatch!");
                    }
```

Comment: Yes it's already shown in scroll

Comment: I mean there probably is another class where you call `SQLHelper.Save_password()` and that's not visible in the code block you posted. I'd like to see how/what values you pass within the password parameter when calling the method.

Comment: Just for clarification, you are **inserting** the same value over and over again, and **not updating**, correct?

Comment: @Tom yes.only one item in table

Comment: i set p_id as return value. the returning p_id is updated...